# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.Title') in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I was making this movie browser project in which I had to fetch data from OMDb API(http://www.omdbapi.com/) and display the data in a Flatlist component.

Although I managed to display 10 results of every movie searched for(as API return 10 items on every call), I added a button that would run a function to send a request again to the API using the page parameter, fetch 10 more results and concatenate the results to the movies.

But as soon as I press the button and run the function, this error appears `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.Title')`.

This is my code for the Home Component => **Home.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList, TouchableHighlight, Image, Button} from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { fetchMovies } from "../api/api";




export default class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: "",
            movies: null,
        };
    }
      //update search text
    componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
        if (this.state.text !== prevState.text) {
            this.getSearch(this.state.text);            
        }
    }
      //get search results from fetchMovies
    getSearch = async text => {
        const results = await fetchMovies(text)
        this.setState({ movies: results });
    };
    

    ////////////////////////////Function making API call using the page parameter///////////
    //loading more movies
    handleLoadMore = async() => {
        try {
            const page = Math.trunc(this.state.movies.length / 10) + 1;
            const res = await fetchMovies(this.state.text, page);
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                movies: prevState.movies.concat(res.movies)
            })) 
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


      //movie title and poster to render in the flatlist
    movieCard = ({ item }) => {
        return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.movieCard}
            underlayColor="white"
            onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
                    title: item.title,
                    id: item.imdbID
                });
            }}
        >
            
            <View>
                <Image
                        style={styles.movieImage}
                        source={ {uri: item.Poster} }                 
                    />
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.movieTitle}>{item.Title} ({item.Year})</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    };
    


render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.searchBox}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize='none'
                autoFocus maxLength={45}
                placeholder='Search'
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                value={this.state.text}
            />

            {this.state.movies ?
            <FlatList
                style={styles.movieList}
                data={this.state.movies}
                renderItem={this.movieCard}
                keyExtractor={item => item.Title + item.imdbID}
                
            />
            :
            <Text
                style={{ 
                    alignSelf: 'center', 
                    paddingTop: 150, 
                    justifyContent: 'center', 
                    color: '#8a8787', 
                    fontStyle: 'italic' }}>
                search for a movie above...
            </Text>
            }

            <Button
                onPress={this.handleLoadMore}
                title="Load More"
                color="#841584"
            />
        </View>
    )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    searchBox: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '300',
        padding: 10,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginBottom: 30
    },
    movieList: {
        flex: 1, 
        marginHorizontal: 30,
    },
    movieCard: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 5,
        padding: 5,
    },
    movieImage: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 350,
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    movieTitle: {
        marginTop: 10,
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#333'
    }
});
```

This is the code for api functions => **api.js**

```
const API_KEY = "API_KEY";


//fetch search data from omdb api
export const fetchMovies = async (response, page) => {
  const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&s=${response}`;
  try {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    if(page) {
      response = await fetch(url + `&page=${page}`)
    }
    const { Search } = await response.json();
    return Search;
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
};

//fetch ID from omdb api
export const fetchById = async id => {
  const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&i=${id}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const results = await response.json();
    return results;
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I know solution to this is probably simple but being new to react-native I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: did you check you api response? maybe the issue is with api response and not your code. Try logging your api response and see if it returns empty, null etc

Comment: You should NEVER post any secret information, such as API keys in questions or answers!

Answer (score 0):

[regarding `FlatList`, In docs they apparently pass lambda which returns rendered items to `renderItem` prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

Also your initialized `state.movies` is null and i think it should be an empty array

```
 this.state = {
   text: "",
   movies: [],
 };

 <FlatList
  style={styles.movieList}
  data={this.state.movies}
  renderItem={({item}) => this.movieCard({item})}
  keyExtractor={item => item.Title + item.imdbID}
```

Comment: I made all these changes and also changed `movies: prevState.movies.concat(res.movies)` int the handleLoadMore function to `movies: prevState.movies.concat(res)`. This although solved the issue I was having. But for some reason changes are not reflected in the Flatlist. Upon logging `this.state.movies` in the console, I do get the concatenated Array. Upon searching for this issue I found extraData as a solution to re-render Flatlist but it is not working.